# Verifying DTFT transform

Tags: summation, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I have the Fourier Transform of the discrete sequence $u_j, j = 0, \pm 1, \pm2, ...$:
$$
\hat{u}(\xi h) = \frac{h}{2\pi}\sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty}u_je^{-ij\xi h}
$$

and wish to verify that the inverse transform is
$$
u_j = \int_{-\pi/h}^{\pi/h} \hat{u}(\xi h)e^{ij\xi h}d\xi
$$

To do that, I try to insert the first form into the second:
$$
\begin{align}
u_j &= \int_{-\pi/h}^{\pi/h} \frac{h}{2\pi}\left(\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}u_ke^{-ik\xi h}\right)e^{ij\xi h}d\xi\\
&= \frac{h}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi/h}^{\pi/h} \left(\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}u_ke^{i(j-k)\xi h}\right)d\xi\\
\end{align}
$$
I've tried expanding the integrand a few times, though haven't landed on anything useful which gives the integration yielding $hu_j/2\pi$, as it should. What must be done?